# Content-Security-Policy issue

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, content-security-policy

I'm using the code below in my htaccess but for some reason I'm getting an error message in the console. Any idea what the issue is?

Thanks,

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/ https://oss.maxcdn.com/ https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://ajax.googleapis.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://fonts.googleapis.com/ https://www.facebook.com/ https://www.facebook.net/ https://connect.facebook.net https://connect.facebook.com"
</IfModule>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an inline script on your page, ie something like this:

```
<script>
...
</script>
```

This is either directly in your HTML or in a component used (e.g. a Facebook widget you pull in to you page adds this) or perhaps in a browser extension your browser uses.

You can allow this online script by adding unsafe-inline to your config like this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/ https://oss.maxcdn.com/ https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://ajax.googleapis.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://fonts.googleapis.com/ https://www.facebook.com/ https://www.facebook.net/ https://connect.facebook.net https://connect.facebook.com"
</IfModule>
```

However this would defeat most of the protections of Content Security Policy (CSP) which is specifically designed to prevent rogue scripts running for your site to prevent security problems like Cross Site Scripting (XSS).

I suggest you read up a lot more on CSP before implementing it. Can suggest my own blog post here as a starter: https://www.tunetheweb.com/security/http-security-headers/csp/