# Content Security Policy error coming up when facebook chat into website?

Tags: facebook

I'm attempting to integrate facebook chat to my website, but get this error:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.12/plugins/customerchat.php?
app_id=166409452530897&channel=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect
%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2FJW5GlLnAsFw.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df1fc7859561b6e%26do
main%3D[domainsnipped]%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252F[domainsnipped]%252Ff17b909ebfe83c4%26relation%3Dparent.parent&container_width=0&locale=
en_US&page_id=857469729300&sdk=joey' in a frame because an ancestor violates 
the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 
https://www.facebook.com".
```

I have added exactly `https://www.example.com/` as a whitelisted domain in my page's settings at https://www.facebook.com/example/settings/?tab=messenger_platform

https://findmyfbid.com/ reports my pageID to be 857469729300

My facebook appID (taken from https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ appears to be 166409452530897, and the app is "live".

This is the code I've got on my site:

```
<div class="fb-customerchat" page_id="857469729300"></div>

<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId            : '166409452530897',
            autoLogAppEvents : true,
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : 'v2.12'
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?  Many thanks!

Comment: See if anything in this helps ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736650/refused-to-display-frame-ancestors-https-www-facebook-com

Comment: Sadly not, I read that and other similar questions on here before posting.

Comment: I don't see any error when loading your site, on which page have you integrated chat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [facebook chat troubleshooting tips](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin#debug-tips):

> If you see a console error like "Refused to display *** in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: ***", check that the domain of the page the plugin is being rendered on has been whitelisted. Also make sure you didn't set the Referrer-Policy header to no-referrer.

In your case, you send `Referrer-Policy: same-origin` response header, which means that the **Referer** request header when an iframe url is requested, is set only for iframe urls of the same domain, not others, in this case www.facebook.com.

So the `Referer: https://www.example.com` request header is not set for the facebook chat url and it could be that you are getting this error because of this.

Change the response header to `origin`.

Eg, with php, do

```
header('Referrer-Policy: origin');
```

Note, you may have to reload the page a couple of times and wait some minutes for this to be "understood" by the browser.

### References

[Referrer-Policy header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy)

[Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Goddammit, I'd tried disabling that header and definitely hard-refreshed the page a few times and it hadn't made a difference.  All I can think is that I'd failed to restart nginx at the time :(  Thank you!

Comment: Would you mind editing the domain name out of your answer please?  Thank you.